# coredump at __correctly_grouped_prefixwc

Tags: c++, gdb

the program under live env, segmentation fault some time,  i try to gdb the coredump file,
but can't found the code line cause coredump.

```
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00000038f3a41bf5 in __correctly_grouped_prefixwc () from /lib64/libc.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00000038f3a41bf5 in __correctly_grouped_prefixwc () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
(gdb) info r
rax            0x1ac1b108       448901384
rbx            0x2add423b4ff0   47129787322352
rcx            0x2add48128640   47129885312576
rdx            0x0      0
rsi            0x1      1
rdi            0x2add48000020   47129884098592
rbp            0x2add3f1aef50   0x2add3f1aef50
rsp            0x2add423b4ff0   0x2add423b4ff0
r8             0x2      2
r9             0x2      2
r10            0x0      0
r11            0x0      0
r12            0x0      0
r13            0x3      3
r14            0x1000   4096
r15            0x2add3f1b0000   47129734873088
rip            0x38f3a41bf5     0x38f3a41bf5 <__correctly_grouped_prefixwc+165>
eflags         0x10246  [ PF ZF IF RF ]
cs             0x33     51
ss             0x2b     43
ds             0x0      0
es             0x0      0
fs             0x0      0
gs             0x0      0
fctrl          0x37f    895
fstat          0x0      0
ftag           0xffff   65535
fiseg          0x0      0
fioff          0xc54f06 12930822
foseg          0x2add   10973
fooff          0x423b3f00       1111179008
fop            0x0      0
mxcsr          0x1fa1   [ IE PE IM DM ZM OM UM PM ]


cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS release 5.5 (Final)
```

and i want to debug glibc at the source level, run `yum install yum-utils` to install the debuginfo-install program.
then, run `sudo debuginfo-install glibc`, the result following

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * addons: centos.ustc.edu.cn
 * base: mirror.bit.edu.cn
 * extras: centos.ustc.edu.cn
 * updates: centos.ustc.edu.cn
Checking for new repos for mirrors
Could not find debuginfo for main pkg: glibc-2.5-123.x86_64
Could not find debuginfo for main pkg: glibc-2.5-123.i686
No debuginfo packages available to install
```

and then i try to run `yum search glibc-debuginfo`

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * addons: centos.ustc.edu.cn
 * base: mirrors.163.com
 * extras: centos.ustc.edu.cn
 * updates: centos.ustc.edu.cn
Warning: No matches found for: glibc-debuginfo
No Matches found
```

no matches found again.

i try to run `yum search glibc`

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * addons: centos.ustc.edu.cn
 * base: mirrors.163.com
 * extras: centos.ustc.edu.cn
 * updates: centos.ustc.edu.cn
================================================================================ Matched: glibc =================================================================================
compat-glibc.i386 : Compatibility C library
compat-glibc.x86_64 : Compatibility C library
compat-glibc-headers.x86_64 : Header files for development using standard C libraries.
glibc.i686 : The GNU libc libraries.
glibc.x86_64 : The GNU libc libraries.
glibc-common.x86_64 : Common binaries and locale data for glibc
glibc-devel.i386 : Object files for development using standard C libraries.
glibc-devel.x86_64 : Object files for development using standard C libraries.
glibc-headers.x86_64 : Header files for development using standard C libraries.
glibc-utils.x86_64 : Development utilities from GNU C library
kernel-headers.x86_64 : Header files for the Linux kernel for use by glibc
nss_db.i386 : An NSS library for the Berkeley DB.
nss_db.x86_64 : An NSS library for the Berkeley DB.
yp-tools.x86_64 : NIS (or YP) client programs.
yum-protect-packages.noarch : Yum plugin to prevents Yum from removing itself and other protected packages
```

i try to run `sudo yum install glibc-devel.x86_64`, and gdb the coredump file again,
but it display the following

```
Reading symbols from /lib64/libc.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib64/libc.so.6
```

how can i find the code line cause coredump? i try to google, but not found, any ideas?

Comment: what's y our exact question?

Comment: _"any ideas?"_ - Use a debugger.

Comment: how can i find the code line cause coredump?

Comment: Get the stack back trace (`where` in `gdb`) and look for your code in the stack trace.  If you compiled with `-g`, you should get line numbers, or an approximation to the line number since optimization can certainly mess things up, as can inline functions.

Comment: Separately, I don't know how much time you spent on the information with the `&nbsp;` etc in the question.  However, it would be simpler if you pasted the information into the question without any markup, and then select it all and use the **`{}`** button above the edit box to indent it all as 'code'.  You can add `<!-- language: lang-none -->` as an unindented comment above it to suppress the colourization.  This gives you constant-width font and makes the output more readable.

Comment: thx, Jonathan, i have already revised.

Comment: To be able to debug glibc at the source level, run `sudo yum install yum-utils`, which will install the `debuginfo-install` program, then run `sudo debuginfo-install glibc`. Then run `gdb` again. Note that the line of code that gets a segmentation violation/coredump may be error-free, and the real cause of the segmentation violation is some other piece of code that has an error in it, for example your program could be passing a NULL pointer to a glibc routine.

Comment: when i run "sudo yum install yum-utils" success, but when i run "sudo debuginfo-install glibc" , not success. Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * addons: centos.ustc.edu.cn
 * base: mirrors.163.com
 * extras: centos.ustc.edu.cn
 * updates: centos.ustc.edu.cn
Checking for new repos for mirrors
Could not find debuginfo for main pkg: glibc-2.5-123.x86_64
Could not find debuginfo for main pkg: glibc-2.5-123.i686
No debuginfo packages available to install

Comment: For some reason your system doesn't have the CentOS Debuginfo repository configured. Look in `/etc/yum.repos.d` for a file named `CentOS-Debuginfo.repo` and check whether the URLs in it are reachable from where you are.  If you don't have that file at all, see the instructions here to add it: http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/DebugInfo . You may get better performance by choosing a server closer to you  than `debuginfo.centos.org`, but I don't have a list of alternative servers.

Comment: You can also download http://debuginfo.centos.org/5/x86_64/glibc-debuginfo-2.5-123.x86_64.rpm and use `rpm -i` to install it. In general, running `debuginfo-install` is better, because it will figure out any package dependencies, and download and install them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, although `__correctly_grouped_prefixwc` caused the segmentation fault, it's likely that it was passed incorrect arguments from some other piece of code, perhaps `strtod` or `strtol` or something that called them. That being said, here is how to set things up so that `gdb` can show the line of source code in `__correctly_grouped_prefixwc` that caused the segmentation fault.

To do source-level debugging, you need an executable or shared object's debug info, and its source code. Linux and Unix distributions in general do not include these by default, to conserve storage space, but they make them available as packages.

On CentOS, you just need to install the **debuginfo** package for each executable or library you're interested in. To do this, run

```
sudo yum install yum-utils
```

which will install the `debuginfo-install` program, then run

```
sudo debuginfo-install glibc
```

to download and install the `glibc-debuginfo-2.5-123` package (your version number may vary). This will install, among many other files, `/usr/lib/debug/lib64/libc.so.6.debug`, `/usr/lib/debug/lib64/libc-2.5.so.debug`, and `/usr/src/debug/glibc-2.5-20061008T1257/stdlib/grouping.c`, which are what you need.

`debuginfo-install` is a short python program that enables the debuginfo repositories and downloads and installs the debuginfo package corresponding to the package you give as an argument, plus all its dependencies. As an alternative, you can download the debuginfo packages directly from http://debuginfo.centos.org (or any mirrors) and install them using `rpm -i`.

You mentioned that you got the error **No debuginfo packages available to install**. Perhaps you don't have the debuginfo repo configured. On my CentOS 5 system, the configuration is in the file `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Debuginfo.repo`

```
# All debug packages from all the various CentOS-5 releases
# are merged into a single repo, split by BaseArch
#
# Note: packages in the debuginfo repo are currently not signed
#

[base-debuginfo]
name=CentOS-5 - Debuginfo
baseurl=http://debuginfo.centos.org/5/$basearch/
gpgcheck=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-5
enabled=0
```

For other releases, general instructions for adding the debuginfo repo are in [this CentOS wiki article](http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/DebugInfo).